# Cannot select right button on ListView with FastScroll enabled

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar

I have a ListView with image on left, title & subtitle in the centre and an ImageButton on the right (this button doesn't have any margin on the right).

[image]

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/contacts"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"/>
```

I have enabled fast scrolling for this ListView. When I try to click the right ImageButton the scrollbar comes in focus and ListView starts scrolling. I am not able to select the button on the right. Please help me out.

Answer (score 4):

**You need to override `ListView` class and its `onInterceptTouchEvent` method.**

```
public class CustomListView extends ListView {
    public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        setFastScrollEnabled(false);
        boolean possibleResult = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        setFastScrollEnabled(true);

        boolean actualResult = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);

        if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            return possibleResult && actualResult;
        }

        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

And it will look like:
[image]

However, the issue which you observe is an **expected** behaviour.
The proper fix would be to add padding to the end of your row.

Take a look on the Google's PhoneBook app, for example:
[image]
As you can see here, the cell-size is smaller, than 100% of screen's width.

I hope, it helps